# Measure ESP32 CPU Utilization

Tags: cpu-usage, esp32

I am communicating two ESP32 boards which are connected to a Wifi Network. One ESP32 board is the Server and the other is the client. I want to measure the ESP32 CPU utlization on the client ESP32. I have no idea how to do it and have not yet found any useful resources on the internet. Can someone help me with this?

This is the code on server

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
const char* ssid = "XXXXX";
const char* password = "XXXX";
AsyncWebServer server(80);
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
while (WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED){
delay(200);
Serial.println("Connecting to Wifi...");
}
Serial.println("Connected to Wifi");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
server.on("/test", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
Serial.println("Request received from esp32client");
request->send(200, "text/plain", "Hello from ESP32Server to ESP32Client");
});
server.on("/test1", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
Serial.println("Request received from PC-Client");
request->send(300, "text/plain", "Hello from ESP32Server to PC");
});

server.begin();

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

This is the code on Client

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
const char* ssid = "XXXXX";
const char* password ="XXXXX";
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
while (WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED){
delay(500);
Serial.println("Connecting to Wifi...");
}
Serial.println("Connected to Wifi Network...");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {

HTTPClient http;

http.begin("http://192.168.43.35/test");
int httpCode = http.GET();

if (httpCode > 0) {

String payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(httpCode);
Serial.println(payload);
}

else {
Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
}

http.end(); 

delay(30000);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this function to get CPU load

```
vTaskGetRunTimeStats(char *buffer);
```

It tells CPU utilization by currently running task on esp32.

API documentation [here](https://demo-dijiudu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/system/freertos.html#_CPPv220vTaskGetRunTimeStatsPc).